# Cognito user pool federated user unable to intiate-auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-cli

Does AWS CLI *cognito-idp initiate-auth* support the *USER_PASSWORD_AUTH* flow for federated users from an external IdP (SAML provider)?

When I try to run initiate-auth, I am getting the below errors.

```
aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --region us-east-1 --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --client-id <my_client_id> --auth-parameters USERNAME=<username>,PASSWORD=<password>

An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: User is not authorized to get auth details.
```

As a debugging step, I created a local user in the userpool, and using that I am able to get an *AuthenticationResult* back.

Also, the username and password work with a browser flow. (It redirects to my app url with the code) when triggered from the *Launch Hosted UI* link.

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, USER_PASSWORD_AUTH is disabled for federated users. The federated users have Confirmation status set to `External Provider` and these users can only login using the 3rd party identity provider.

The problem may be solved using Account linking.
Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation-consolidate-users.html

I want to know if initiate-auth is supported for federated users but for CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATION. My research so far shows that this is not possible.